# Using approximate solutions and bisection search

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, bisection

I wanted to make it clear that this question is from the EDX python course for Intro to Comp Sci (free online course) and i have seen many answers online. I want to figure out why this specific code enters into a infinite loop, not ways to change my code completely (unless its fundamentally wrong...)

Mainly, why is this failing:

```
while abs(balance - fixedP*12)  >= epsilon:
```

The goal of the program is to find the smallest monthly payment to the cent such that we can pay off the balance within a year.

My code below arrives at the amount (can be found if you insert a print (fixedP) statement in the middle of the while loop but it gets stuck in a infinite loop. I believe my condition is failing and i cannot figure out why. When balance becomes "29157.09", and my (fixedP * 12) check also becomes 29157.09, i thought the while loop would stop. But, it keeps getting stuck.

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = .2 
#above is given, below is my code

epsilon = 0.01  #precision check
balanceD = balance  #copy of balance
month = 0  #counter
monthlyRate = annualInterestRate/12  #given formula for problem

#bisection search parameters using given forumulas
low = balance / 12
high = (balance * (1+monthlyRate)**12)/12

fixedP = (low + high) / 2.0  #midpoint


while abs(balance - fixedP*12)  >= epsilon:
  unpaid = balance - fixedP
  newB = unpaid + monthlyRate*unpaid
  balance = newB
  month += 1

  if(month == 12 and balance > 0): #set new lower bound since original guess was too low
    low = fixedP
    fixedP = (high + low)/2
    balance = balanceD
    month = 0
  elif(month == 12 and balance < 0): #set new higher bound since original guess was too high
    high = fixedP
    fixedP = (low + high)/2
    balance = balanceD
    month = 0

print('Lowest Payment: ', round(fixedP, 2))
```

The above code arrives at the fixed monthly amount but it gets stuck in a infinite loop at the amount. It never exits the while loop. Are you able to help me figure out why my while loop condition is failing?

Thanks.

Comment: check `balance` and `fixedP` anytime it's being set by printing it, to see where it is being set. This is debugging from the schoolbooks you need to do, no magic.

Comment: Print and tracing balance - fixedP*12, then you will know why...

Comment: I can see that balance is never approaching (fixedP*12), which is weird because the actual value for fixedP is approaching what it should be (29157.09).

Comment: Essentially, i am trying to do "While (you are still not within the desired range of the answer) : ", and while i think my loop condition looks to do that, it is never reaching a difference of 0

Comment: @ critcoder, can you share us the original question here. The problem is not with abs(balance - fixedP*12)  >= epsilon, is other part of the code, so we need to know the logic behind first.

Comment: Hi @Marcus.Aurelianus, sure. I think you need a login to access the question directly, so here is a github version https://github.com/anarayanan86/MITx-6.00.1x/blob/master/Week_2-_Simple_Programs/Problem_Set_2/Problem_3.py.     The above contains a solution but i want to find why my answer is incorrect. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @critcoder, consider accept answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic and everything else is correct. But your while function logic is somehow not right, you should donot compare while abs(balance - fixedP*12) >= epsilon. It should be either:

```
while balance >= epsilon:
```

Or:

```
abs(balance - fixedP*(12-month))  >= epsilon:
```

Also, you need to compare balance with epsilon instead of 0 in the later comparison.

Because the balance should be the value that deducted from your months left, so you should not use 12 here.

And your code there

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = .2 
#above is given, below is my code

epsilon = 0.01  #precision check
balanceD = balance  #copy of balance
month = 0  #counter
monthlyRate = annualInterestRate/12  #given formula for problem

#bisection search parameters using given forumulas
low = balance / 12
high = (balance * (1+monthlyRate)**12)/12

fixedP = (low + high) / 2.0  #midpoint


while balance >= epsilon:
    unpaid = balance - fixedP
    newB = unpaid + monthlyRate*unpaid
    balance = newB
    month += 1
    if(month == 12 and balance > epsilon): #set new lower bound since original guess was too low
        low = fixedP
        fixedP = (high + low)/2
        balance = balanceD
        month = 0
    elif(month == 12 and balance < -epsilon): #set new higher bound since original guess was too high
        high = fixedP
        fixedP = (low + high)/2
        balance = balanceD
        month = 0


print('Lowest Payment: ', round(fixedP, 2))
```

Alternately, you can use break function to exit the while loop when you got the desired value:

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = .2 
#above is given, below is my code

epsilon = 0.01  #precision check
balanceD = balance  #copy of balance
month = 0  #counter
monthlyRate = annualInterestRate/12  #given formula for problem

#bisection search parameters using given forumulas
low = balance / 12
high = (balance * (1+monthlyRate)**12)/12

fixedP = (low + high) / 2.0  #midpoint


while True:
    unpaid = balance - fixedP
    newB = unpaid + monthlyRate*unpaid
    balance = newB
    month += 1
    if(month == 12 and balance > epsilon): #set new lower bound since original guess was too low
        low = fixedP
        fixedP = (high + low)/2
        balance = balanceD
        month = 0
    elif(month == 12 and balance < -epsilon): #set new higher bound since original guess was too high
        high = fixedP
        fixedP = (low + high)/2
        balance = balanceD
        month = 0
    else:
        break

print('Lowest Payment: ', round(fixedP, 2))
```

Feel free to post any thing you not clear. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify this "Also, you need to compare balance with epsilon instead of 0 in the later comparison.
"

Comment: @critcode, because your precision is epsilon. So in every loop, you need to compare balance with epsilon, if the current precision fall inside range [-epsilon,epsilon], it means you have achieved the desired precision and can break from the function there.

Comment: "while balance >= epsilon", this makes sure i break when i am within the precision, what does "balance > epsilon" and "balance <- epsilon" do? same thing?

Comment: @ critcoder, emm, should be @"balance > epsilon" and "balance <- epsilon" , because if you use 0, if will reset your balance every time and causing a infinite loop....

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I see here is more of an economics problem than a Python problem.

That being said, to make your code work, we first add the following line before the while block:

```
series_pw_factor = ((1+monthlyRate)**11 - 1) / (monthlyRate*(1+monthlyRate)**11)
```

And then we can modify your condition as follows:

```
while abs(balanceD - fixedP*series_pw_factor - fixedP)  >= epsilon:
```

Now for an explanation of how Economics ties into this problem:

The issue with your while condition is that it does not account for the time value of money(i.e. interest). If you take out a loan for $1000 today and pay $200 a month (at the end of each month) for 5 months, you will still owe money on the loan at the end of the 5 months if the interest is non zero.

While it wasn't explicitly stated in the problem, to get the answer '29157.09' you must assume that the first payment is made at the beginning of the first month and the last payment is made at the beginning of the 12th month.

The payment structure is as follows:

Initial Balance: $320000

Payment 1 at t = 0(beginning of month 1): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^0 = 29157.09

Payment 2 at t = 1(beginning of month 2): 29157.09,

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^1 = 28679.10

Payment 3 at t = 2(beginning of month 3): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^2 = 28208.96

Payment 4 at t = 3(beginning of month 4): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^3 = 27746.51

Payment 5 at t = 4(beginning of month 5): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^4 = 27291.65

Payment 6 at t = 5(beginning of month 6): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^5 = 26844.25

Payment 7 at t = 6(beginning of month 7): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^6 = 26404.18

Payment 8 at t = 7(beginning of month 8): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^7 = 25971.32

Payment 9 at t = 8(beginning of month 9): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^8 = 25545.56

Payment 10 at t = 9(beginning of month 10): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^9 = 25126.78

Payment 11 at t = 10(beginning of month 11): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^10 = 24714.87

Payment 12 at t = 11(beginning of month 12): 29157.09

value at t = 0 is 29157.09 / (1+monthlyRate)^11 = 24309.71

When you sum the value at t = 0 for each payment,
it will equal the initial balance, $320000

The pattern here is that we are essentially solving:

(1) initial_balance = payment*sum(1/(1+monthlyRate)^i) for i in [0,11]

or

(2) initial_balance = (payment at t = 0) + payment*sum(1/(1+monthlyRate)^i) for i in [1,11]

In (2), The term 'sum(1/(1+monthlyRate)^i) for i in [1,11]' is 
known as the Uniform Series Present Worth Factor

This is what the variable series_pw_worth factor means.

The condition for the while makes sure that (2) is satisfied.

Using (2), we can also see that a one-line solution O(1) is:

```
fixedP = balance / (1 + ((1+annualInterestRate/12)**11 - 1) / (annualInterestRate/12*(1+annualInterestRate/12)**11))
```